# Laravel eloquent with relation data (Eager Loading)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have two database tables `items` and `measurement_units` - item has measurement unit.

Now the problem is I want to **select** a particular column from `items` and some column from `measurement_unit`. I want to use **Eager loading**

e.g.

```
$items_with_mu = Item::with("measurement_unit")->select(["item_name", "item_stock"])->first();
```

When accessing measurement_unit. It returns **null**. Without the select function it returns data(measurement_unit).

```
$items_with_mu->measurement_unit;
```

can anyone help me and sorry for my English.

Comment: But I need to select column. I got my answer. BDW thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Item::with(['measurement_unit' => function($q) { 
           $q->select('id','unit_column');   //specified measurement_unit column
      }])
     ->select('id','measurement_unit_id','item_name')
     ->get();
```

If your laravel version is >=5.5 then you can write in a single line

```
Item::with('measurement_unit:id,unit_column')
     ->select('id','measurement_unit_id','item_name')
     ->get()
```

Comment: should be work select foreign key `measurement_unit_id`. check latest code

Comment: Glade to help you. you should check updated answer if your laravel version is >=5.5

Comment: now I got the point where I am missing. without foreign key how a table can be  join.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the primary column of the main model like below.

```
 items_with_mu = Item::with("measurement_unit")->select(["item_name", "item_stock", "primary_key"])->first();
```

Comment: Can you please paste your relationship method?

Comment: Also database structure as well.

Comment: `primary_key` should be `foreing key`. after adding foreign key it works.

Comment: @ThataL I'm talking about the primary column of Item model.

Comment: Ok my mistake (**primary key of another model**). accept my edit I will vote as answer. Description is minimum that's why it make me confused.

Comment: Your edit request content is incorrect. My above select method only for Item model. It won't reflect for relationship model.